# Удаление элемента из списка по вводу python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список из имен. Хочу удалять тот элемент, который введу, но почему-то не получается. В чем ошибка?

```
contacts_list = 'contacts_list.txt'
names = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь']

del_name = input('Введите имя, которое хотите удалить: ')
f = open(contacts_list, 'rb')
storedcontacts = pickle.load(f)
for name in names:
    if name == del_name:
        del name
        print('Вы удалили имя: {0}'.format(name))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Потому что вы удаляете переменную name, которая не имеет никакого отношения к элементам списка

Comment: еще прерываете цикл командой `break`, нужно просто `pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь']

del_name = input('Введите имя, которое хотите удалить: ')
for name in names:
    if name == del_name:
        names.remove(name)
        print('Вы удалили имя: {0}'.format(name))
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Не надо ничего удалять. Просто пересоздайте список с только нужными элементами:

```
names = [n for n in names if n != 'del_name']
```

Если непременно нужно показать сообщение столько раз, сколько имён было удалено из списка, то можно просто запомнить длину списка до пересоздания, и сравнить её с длиной после - разница и будет количеством удалённых элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяете что введенное имя есть в списке и удаляете, циклы тут не нужны:

```
names = ['Сергей', 'Маша', 'Алена', 'Игорь']

del_name = input('Введите имя, которое хотите удалить: ')
if del_name in names:
    names.remove(del_name)
    print('Вы удалили имя:', del_name)
```